# Transaction partially committing or rolling back

Tags: java, transactions, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I am facing some issue with transactions configured in my code.
Below is the code with transactions which writes data to DB.

**Writer.java**

```
class Writer {

    @Inject
    private SomeDAO someDAO;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void write(){
        this.batchWrite();

    }


    private void batchWrite () {

        try {
            someDAO.writeToTable1(true);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            someDAO.writeToTable1(false);
        }

        someDAO.writeToTable2();

    }
}
```

**SomeDAO.java**

```
class SomeDAO {

    @Inject
    private JdbcTemplate JdbcTemplate;

    public void writeToTable1(boolean flag) {
        // Writes data to table 1 using jdbcTemplate
        jdbcTemplate.update();
    }


    pulic void writeToTable2() {
        // Writes data to table 2 using jdbcTemplate
        jdbcTemplate.update();
    }

}
```

Here data is getting stored into table 1 properly but sometimes, table 2 is getting skipped.

I am not sure how this is happening as both the tables have been written within same transaction.

Either transaction is partially committing the data or partially rolling back.

I have doubt that in the `SomeDAO` class I am injecting `JdbcTemplate` object which is creating new connection instead of using existing connection of transaction.

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding a Transaction Manager bean having your **jdbcTemplate** inside @Transactional:

```
    //Create a bean
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txnManager() throws Exception {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(jdbcTemplate().getDataSource());
    }
```

And then use this transaction manager in @Transactional("txnManager").

Comment: @Guarav Its already done
```@Bean(name = "datastoreTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("datastoreEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }```

Comment: Are you using same entityManagerFactory for write operations?